# is there any video player which can bookmark in video at various places?

Tags: windows-xp, video

is there any video player which can bookmark in video at various places?

update:

my brother watch video tutorials and he just to place a reminder or bookmark like thing at various places in video where he couldn't understand the thing which is happening in video so when i will go to home then he can ask and remember easily that places in video

Answer (score 4):

Most video players can do this. [VLC](http://videolan.org) allows you to set custom hotkeys for bookmarks and manage the bookmarks easily, which makes things even easier for you:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i need to make bookmark in a single video file

Comment: Like a permanent bookmark that other people can see when they open the file?

Comment: not permanent but like we make boomark in pdf and word

Comment: see update in question

Comment: Ah. VLC can save bookmarks for later which should give you the functionality you require: http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_save_bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Contenta Video Browser](http://www.contenta-videobrowser.com). It lets you access your bookmark with a thumbnail to know where you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "transfer" bookmarks, like John T suggested, [The KMPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_KMPlayer) can do that. Download it and install it. It will save all bookmarks in a very simple file called BookMark.ini in its directory. The file contains something like this:

```
[C:\Documents and Settings\ldigas\Desktop\birthday_vids\spt0003.avi]
00:38:12=2292
01:05:29=3929
01:06:42=4002
```

where the time stamps are the bookmarks. You can ship it with the video file, and using the reverse procedure reproduce the bookmarks on another computer.